# Why is the code in the thread executed twice?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

As indicated in the title, why is the following code executed twice (2x `Test` in the console) and how to fix it?

```
type
  TSelfThread = class(TThread)
    procedure Execute; override;
end;

procedure TSelfThread.Execute;
begin
  Writeln('Test');
end;

var
  SelfThread : TSelfThread;
begin
  try
    SelfThread := TSelfThread.Create(False);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln('Error');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. In any case, you do need to wait for the thread to finish. Add a call to `SelfThread.WaitFor`.

Comment: What version of Delphi?  Can't reproduce.

Comment: Delphi 10.3 Community. I recompiled the tool under another name. The first start it prints 2x "Test" and after that no output???? https://prnt.sc/nv00cx

Comment: And what happens when you correct the code by making it wait for the thread to finish?

Comment: Now it works.. Thank you. But why did it do such unexpected things without it?

Comment: Well, you start a thread, and before you are certain that is has finished executing, you end the process. Anything can happen.

Comment: Now my question might be stupid, But how did you see the second Test. The console would blink. I mean did you log the console output or put the readln; before the end of the block?.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Any thing can happen. But I do not think calling the execute again is something you want to be possible. The rtl should prevent this.

Comment: @Nasreddine Galfout Without the SelfThread.WaitFor; i get 2x "Test" or no ouput. I did not change anything.

Comment: @Nasfeddine How could it do that? And why should it?

Comment: @Nasreddine open a console and execute a process, console doesn't disappear when the process terminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible explanation for this behaviour is the bug in your code where you fail to wait for the thread to complete before terminating the process.

Change the code to be like this:

```
SelfThread := TSelfThread.Create(False);
SelfThread.WaitFor;
```